# forest of a graph $G=(V,E)$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I have the following problem.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph and $W=(V,F)$ with $F\subset E$

Proof: $W$ is a forest if and only if $E\setminus F$ is an inclusion maximal set that does not contain an inclusion minimal cut.

Would appreciate any help

Is this correct for the first part ?

Comment: @bof Sry, I edited my question. $E/F$ was supposed to be the setminus which I edited now